# how can i make an angular app (embeded on diffrent sites) span all the way to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

I developed a component using angular that I embed in clients sites.
I want the component to span minimally until the end of the viewport.
each of the sites has a different size header and the headers doesn't share a tag/class/id.
I need to add min-height value to the app that equals to viewport height - header height and that way, even if the content of my component wont be enough to reach the bottom of the viewport, the min-height will enforce it spanning all the way to it.

previously I handled those problems with the following JS code

```
var component= document.getElementById("component")
component.minHeight = Window.innerHeight - component.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

but that doesn't work in angular...

any idea how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
    #component {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

In css set min-height to 100vh and parent component too.

I think it's simpler with css than javascript or typescript.

Comment: it cant be 100vh, I want it to occupy 100% - header height...
the header size is changing from site to site so it has to be JS/TS as far as i know